# Python requests: NewConnectionError, urllib3, using cert and verify attributes

Tags: python, ssl, https, python-requests, urllib3

So the program i am developing involves posting documents in bank DMS server. They have provided me server certificate in .cer format which i have inserted in my verify variable in code. They also provided client id and password which i have to embed in the header itself. I generated self signed client certificate and private key and gave them the client certificate in cer format and public key. Also in code i gave path of client certificate and private key in cert tuple.
Upon executing code, i am getting this error:

```
    HTTPSConnectionPool(host='apimuat.xxxbank.com', port=9095): Max retries exceeded with url: /doc-mgmt/v1/uploadDoc (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fb01bd8a160>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 60] Operation timed out'))


File "/Users/fpl_mayank/Documents/FPL/python-virtual-env/uploadDocApi/server.py", line 164, in main
    result = requests.post(url,
  File "/Users/fpl_mayank/Documents/FPL/python-virtual-env/uploadDocApi/server.py", line 189, in <module>
    main()
```

I have tested it with 'https://postman-echo.com/post' without mentioning cert and verify just to check if my request is going through or not. it is working fine there.

This is my code snippet where i am using request functions.

```
url='https://apimuat.xxxbank.com:9095/doc-mgmt/v1/uploadDoc'
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json", "client_id":"af197b22539647fba4db8b971b43e38", 
           "client_secret":"c1AA406e24074d8887954472C78a924"}
data = req
result = requests.post(url,
             data=data,
             headers=headers,
             cert=('/Users/fpl_mayank/Documents/FPL/python-virtual- 
env/uploadDocApi/keystore/dms_csr_certificate_self.cer','/Users/fpl_mayank/Documents/FPL/python-virtual-env/uploadDocApi/keystore/dms_private_key.key'),
             verify='/Users/fpl_mayank/Documents/FPL/python-virtual-env/uploadDocApi/truststore/APIM-UAT.cer'
             )
        
        res = result.json()
```

In apidoc it was mentioned, 2-way SSL authentication will be implemented bw client and server. Also i have made virtual-env for this program for that matter. Please help. I am the first one to write an API using python in my company so only way to get my issue resolve is through good ol stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

So i solved this. idk exactly what solved it but make sure when working on api's, get the endpoint's ip whitelisted from your network, as per requirement and same goes from their side too. Also i was sending formatted json request having identation and spaces so make sure to keep json in one line.